# Changing vertex array object

Tags: opengl

Lets see this code:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &name);
glBindVertexArray(name);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer1);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);

(...)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer2);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);

(...)

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

What happens if I decide to do something like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(name);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer3);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);

(...)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer4);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);

(...)

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

?
Can I change vertex declaration layout this way? Are there ways to do it?

Comment: Um, yes, by doing exactly what you wrote?

Comment: sorry, dont recognized which of questions you answered. What happens when I call glVeretexAttribPointer once again? Will any previous glVeretexAttribPointer's be deleted or somewhat?

Comment: Yes, it will replace the previous binding made.

Comment: so, if I need to change only one buffer for binding, I have to reset others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's precisely why a simple solution to avoiding VAO's altogether is generating and binding a single one at program start. However, that mitigates any performance benefits you may gain -- switching VAOs is (or should be) faster than redefining the vertex layout.