# PyOpenGL how to rebind VAO to another VBO in order to quickly switch data that needs to be drawn

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, pyopengl

I am using PyQt5 QOpenGLWidget to simply draw some points on the screen with different colors. I prepared two datasets, each containing their coordinates and their colors, 4 arrays on total, and I want the program to paint one of the datasets for each 100ms (by using a QTimer). I put these 4 arrays into 4 VBOs, and for each paintGL() call I want to switch from a dataset to another, that is, if this frame uses VBO0(coordinate), VBO1(color), then next frame will use VBO2(coordinate),  VBO3(color), and vice versa.

My idea is to use a VAO, and since VBO0/1 has exactly same structure with VBO2/3, for each new frame I can just rebind the VAO to another VBO. However this does not work as expected, so what is the correct way of achieving my goal?

Minimum Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget, QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

from OpenGL.GL import *


def compileShader(vsSource, fsSource):

    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource)
    glCompileShader(vertexShader)

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource)
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader)

    program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader)
    glLinkProgram(program)

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader)
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader)

    return program


class MyOpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

   


    def initializeGL(self):

        # with open('./shaders/vertexShader.shader', 'r') as f:
        #     vsSource = f.read()
        # with open('./shaders/fragmentShader.shader', 'r') as f:
        #     fsSource = f.read()

        vsSource = """
        #version 450 core
        layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
        layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
        
        out vec4 vs_Color;
        
        void main() {
        
            gl_Position = position;
            gl_PointSize = 5.;
            vs_Color = color;
        
        }
        """

        fsSource = """
        #version 450 core
        out vec4 FragColor;

        in vec4 vs_Color;
        
        void main() {
        
            FragColor = vs_Color;
        
        }
        """

        self.program = compileShader(vsSource, fsSource)
        self.initBuffers()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        self.timer.start(100)
        self.dataset = 1


    def paintGL(self):

        bgColor = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.float32)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, bgColor)
        glUseProgram(self.program)
        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, self.n)


    def generateRandomData(self, n, mode='vertex'):

        if mode == 'vertex':
            dx = np.random.rand(n) * 2 - 1
            dy = np.random.rand(n) * 2 - 1
            zeros = np.zeros(n)
            ones = np.ones(n)
            data = np.vstack([dx, dy, zeros, ones]).T.astype(np.float32)
            return data.flatten()

        elif mode == 'color':
            r = np.random.rand(n)
            g = np.random.rand(n)
            b = np.random.rand(n)
            ones = np.ones(n)
            data = np.vstack([r, g, b, ones]).T.astype(np.float32)
            return data.flatten()


    def initBuffers(self):

        self.n = 100
        self.vertexData1 = self.generateRandomData(self.n, mode='vertex')
        self.colorData1 = self.generateRandomData(self.n, mode='color')
        self.vertexData2 = self.generateRandomData(self.n, mode='vertex')
        self.colorData2 = self.generateRandomData(self.n, mode='color')

        self.buffers = np.empty(4, dtype=np.uint32)
        glCreateBuffers(4, self.buffers)

        for buffer in self.buffers:
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
            glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, self.vertexData1.nbytes, None,
                                 GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT)

        glNamedBufferSubData(self.buffers[0], 0, self.vertexData1.nbytes, self.vertexData1)
        glNamedBufferSubData(self.buffers[1], 0, self.colorData1.nbytes, self.colorData1)
        glNamedBufferSubData(self.buffers[2], 0, self.vertexData2.nbytes, self.vertexData2)
        glNamedBufferSubData(self.buffers[3], 0, self.colorData2.nbytes, self.colorData2)

        self.VAO = GLuint(0)
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, self.VAO)

        glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(self.VAO, 0)
        glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(self.VAO, 1)
        glVertexArrayAttribFormat(self.VAO, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0)
        glVertexArrayAttribFormat(self.VAO, 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0)
        glVertexArrayAttribBinding(self.VAO, 0, 0)
        glVertexArrayAttribBinding(self.VAO, 1, 1)

        glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 0, self.buffers[0], 0, 4 * 4)
        glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 1, self.buffers[1], 0, 4 * 4)


        glBindVertexArray(self.VAO)


    def onTimeout(self):

        if self.dataset == 1:
            glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 0, self.buffers[2], 0, 4 * 4)
            glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 1, self.buffers[3], 0, 4 * 4)
            self.dataset = 2
        elif self.dataset == 2:
            glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 0, self.buffers[0], 0, 4 * 4)
            glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(self.VAO, 1, self.buffers[1], 0, 4 * 4)
            self.dataset = 1
        self.update()


app = QApplication([])
win = QWidget()
win.showMaximized()
layout = QHBoxLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(MyOpenGLWidget())
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Expected Output:

Two datsets switches on the screen every 100ms (as set in QTimer) like:
[image]

Real Output:

First frame is correct, but after first switching there is a white triangle on the screen instead of points, and there's no further effect.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebind your vertex array object (self.VAO) each time in `paintGL` rather than just once in `initBuffers`. The official doco is not very clear, but these earlier answers suggest that changing attribs on a VAO probably won't take effect on the current binding.

[When is What bound to a VAO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552642/when-is-what-bound-to-a-vao)

[Changing vertex array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041786/changing-vertex-array-object)

Comment: Moving VAO rebinding to `paintGL` indeed works! Thanks for your hint.